# Monero pizza day

Tags: history

When was the first time Monero was used to pay for pizza delivery to a castle?

- Who ordered the pizza?
- Where did this happen?
- How many pizzas were ordered and for what price?
- Are there any pictures or videos of this historic moment?

Most importantly are there any plans to formally establish a Monero pizza day based on the above event similar to the widely celebrated [Bitcoin pizza day](http://www.coindesk.com/bitcoin-pizza-day-celebrating-pizza-bought-10000-btc/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Afaik, there was something like a Monero Pizza Day in August (24th?) 2014.

Two delicious(?) Pizza were delivered to Malla Castle/Estonia ordered by MEW member Risto Pietila. The price was said to have been 10 XMR.

I've found the following video of this event: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwetOo6gqZQ

Additional sources on this topic:
https://plus.google.com/+DavidLatapie/posts/PX5gcyLondf (witness, one of the eaters)
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=634978.msg8187288#msg8187288 (post by rpietila that got it all started)