# Any plans to have a Monero convention?

Tags: monero-community

Bitcoin and Ethereum seem to have meetups/convention every now an then, are there any plans to do this with monero?

Comment: @SmartKid Why did you reopen this? This is not at all a practical question about the Monero cryptocurrency -- it's a discussion question for a forum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Silicon Valley Monero meetup just announced:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5h9zo0/silicon_valley_monero_meetup/

Answer (score 6):

There is a [meetup](https://www.meetup.com/Monero-JHB-Community/events/235861676/) scheduled for the 17th of December in Johannesburg.

There have [also](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5fgjp0/desire_for_a_minneapolis_mn_usa_meetup/?st=iwcs3npu&sh=b56713ad) been [other](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4p7ifg/silicon_valley_bay_area_monero_meetup/?ref=search_posts) suggestions for a monero meetup.

However, an official convention as not been discussed publicly AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

There was a MRL meetup in [Utah](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/1059/121) back in 2014:

> Over the weekend of the 8th and 9th of November 2014, the Monero Research Lab had a closed mini-meetup in Salt Lake City, Utah, USA. In attendance were surae, sarang, and shen, as well as tewinget and fluffypony.

There also have been some informal Monero meetings at the [Malla castle](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/845/121) in Estonia.

> Two delicious(?) Pizza were delivered to Malla Castle/Estonia ordered by MEW member Risto Pietila. The price was said to have been 10 XMR.

If you count Monero live presentations at Bitcoin related conventions, more examples can be given such as from the [Amsterdam Bitcoinference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEVm1dMn5Ks) in 2015 and the Arnhem [Bitcoin in Use](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVlQE-ObEXk) conference on may 28th 2016.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the meetings above, a new [Monero London](https://www.meetup.com/Monero-London/) meetup group was recently announced on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5gfwxz/new_monero_london_meetup_group_join_us/)